# Python remove function doesn't remove all matching integers from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm very new to python so this might well be a silly question. I am trying to remove all negative values and 0 from a list of integers:

```
def solution(A):
    for i in A:
        print(i)
        if i <= 0:
            A.remove(i)
    return set(A)

A = [-3,-1,0,-1,3,4,0,10,3,7,8,-10,-9,-78]
```

I've tested shorter list like [-3,-2,0,1,2,3] to long lists like the one above. However, when I run the code, there is always at least one negative value left in the list A. This particular code outputs:

```
{-9, -1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10}
```

I can't see why it doesn't remove all the negative values. Could someone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Classic mutation during iteration.

```
>>> A = [-3,-1,0,-1,3,4,0,10,3,7,8,-10,-9,-78]
>>> [a for a in A if a > 0]
[3, 4, 10, 3, 7, 8]
```

Does this do you what you're looking for?

Comment: It did indeed. Thank you so much